# I get an application error when opening app

Tags: heroku

On Heroku i can build the app perfectly fine but when i try to open it, it says to check the logs. This is the log:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> worker
-----> Compressing...
   Done: 80.4M
-----> Launching...
   Released v4
   https://nedtrainbot.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: You only have a worker process, what is it actually? If there's no web process **running** you'll get the application error

Comment: my worker process is a python file , do i need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Dyno workers are for background jobs: It runs in the background to perform some logic, batch processing or even accessing services over HTTP. It cannot respond to incoming requests.

You will have to use a Web Dyno to be able to see something when opening the application with the browser: this typically calls the home of your application. You need to use some web framework (ie Django) or library (ie Flask) to get the incoming request and respond to it